# Login automatically as root at startup

Tags: boot, root, login

Is there a way to auto login as root at startup with Raspbian Jessie like there are auto login for user `pi`?

Comment: This is a major security hole. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: to save time, because always login as root anyway

Comment: So taking 10 seconds to login is worth hosing your system? There is nothing you can't do as the Pi user with sudo.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root

Comment: If you're using a Unix based OS and logging in as root regularly you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I feel like the downvotes on this question are poor form. It's a foolish choice on Redex's part, but it's not a bad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MariusMatutiaes accepted answer worked for Raspbian Jessie (March 2016) too:

Edit the file `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` and change the line

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
```

to

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/getty/ --noclear -a root %I $TERM
```

Reference: https://superuser.com/a/970013

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you would want to autologin as root, but if its just for the sake of saving those few seconds you can choose to auto login with the pi username in the raspi-config settings:

[image: Auto Login as "pi"]

Comment: I know, but Pi-user isn't root and needs sudo-command and I was asking automatically login as root...

Comment: From a security point of view autologin is a bad choice, but this is moderately better solution (and hence a valid answer)

Comment: I tried this with B2 option and all works as expected. Do you know what files raspi-config actually changes when setting this auto login option ? All I can see it doing is creating a symbolic link between default.target and multi-user.target inside systemd services folders. How does it work ?

Comment: Q: How to login as `root`? A: Login as `pi`. This doesn't answer the question, regardless of which is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, if you need to auto-login to Desktop as `root`, you can do the following:

- configure the `pi` user to autologin using `raspi-config`
- replace `autologin-user=pi` to `autologin-user=root` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
- reboot

Steve already warned about the dangers of `root` login from security standpoint. When logging to Desktop, more issues arise which will affect even basic usability:

- PulseAudio will run in [system mode](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/), which is slower and has less features (that is, in addition to being less secure)
- Many software packages will refuse to run as `root` (at least without hacks), or will be missing essential features: [`chromium`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451290/how-to-run-chromium-as-root), [`tor`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211131/unable-to-run-tor-in-kali-as-root), [`and`](https://sourceforge.net/p/and/feature-requests/1/), [`xscreensaver`](http://devwithopinions.blogspot.de/2012/11/how-to-run-xscreensaver-as-root-with.html) and many more. Example:

[image]

- graphical file managers will become really dangerous: a single misclick can e.g. drag&drop your `/etc` inside `/lib`, completely ruining your system.
- since `root` processes are considered more valuable by OOM killer, opening a huge file in GIMP or a buggy webpage in your browser is likely to kill a few innocent processes along the way.

So, even if you don't care about security, you should consider whether saving those 10 seconds to type in `sudo` is worth all the time you will lose fixing misbehaving software and risking a reboot after each browser crash.

Comment: I get really tired of this root paranoia, I've been logging in as root for 20 years.  Not that I never made a mistake but I didn't do it twice, and I had to fix what I broke or reinstall.

Comment: I wouldn't have my mother do it, or most undergrads.  Having your processes run with elevated privileges is maybe the worst part.